# How to interpret output of config show from numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

Trouble in understanding the output of `__config__.show()` from the `numpy` module in Python2.7.

Following is the output from executing the above command:

```
>>> numpy.__config__.show()
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'iomp5', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/r/ge.unx.xxx.com/vol/vol110/u11/jack/anaconda2/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/r/ge.unx.xxx.com/vol/vol110/u11/jack/anaconda2/include']
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'iomp5', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/r/ge.unx.xxx.com/vol/vol110/u11/jack/anaconda2/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/r/ge.unx.xxx.com/vol/vol110/u11/jack/anaconda2/include']
lapack_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'iomp5', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/r/ge.unx.xxx.com/vol/vol110/u11/jack/anaconda2/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/r/ge.unx.xxx.com/vol/vol110/u11/jack/anaconda2/include']
blas_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'iomp5', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/r/ge.unx.xxx.com/vol/vol110/u11/jack/anaconda2/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/r/ge.unx.xxx.com/vol/vol110/u11/jack/anaconda2/include']
>>>
```

From the above output I wanted to infer whether `numpy` is using Intel MKL library or not. If yes, what is the location for the library?

Comment: FYI: Another name for the function is `numpy.show_config()`.